# Android: log cluttered with "D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer"

Tags: android

Whenever I touch the screen on the device of my app the log shows:

`D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1`

This happens on any view of the app. I tried to google any of this, but no luck.
I have no clue what this means or how to track down where this comes from. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure on this but I believe that's just a log showing that touch input was detected. I don't know the exact meaning of it but it is normal. Anything in logcat that starts with a D indicates "debug." This is not meant to be an error necessarily it is just providing more information for someone debugging. Errors will start with an E, but again do not always indicate something is completely broken. Additionally I is for info.

If you don't want to see these messages and only want to see errors you can set logcats display mode to "Error." In Android Studio there is a dropdown for this above the log on the right side.

However, I recommend using logging for your own debugging purposes. I use it all the time to output variables that could cause crashes if they were incorrect, or incoming JSON data if I suspect I'm not parsing it correctly, or even just to log "SUCCESSFULLY MADE IT TO XXX METHOD," if I'm not sure the method is hitting.